# Ask for sql dilettante, who can tell me whether this sql is efficient?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am writing a sql like that

```
SELECT uid
  FROM search
 WHERE MATCH(product) AGAINST('football basketball')
   AND status=1
 ORDER BY MATCH(product) AGAINST('football basketball') DESC
```

I run it ok in mysql,but I am not sure whether it is efficient. I want to know whether this "**MATCH(product) AGAINST('football basketball')**" run twice?

Comment: Wouldn't a: ORDER BY product DESC do the same job?

Comment: @PanagiotisPalladinos, `MATCH...AGAINST` can return the relevance of the match.  However, there appear to be some tricky aspects to that.  Check out the second comment on this documentation page: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html

Answer (score 0):

This might work without worries:

```
SELECT uid, MATCH(product) AGAINST('football basketball') as imatch
  FROM search
 WHERE imatch 
  AND status=1
 ORDER BY imatch DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to select the match as well you would need to put the alias in the where clause. But aliases only run once and store the result in the "variable"

```
SELECT uid
FROM search
WHERE MATCH(product) AGAINST('football basketball') as imatch
AND status = 1
ORDER BY imatch DESC
```